# Separating different parts of the project in Git

Tags: laravel, git, api, laravel-8

How can I efficiently separate different parts of the project in Git? I have a Laravel web application that includes admin panel + API for Mobile app to increase performance. I thought it would be a good idea to separate the admin part from the API to disable a service provider in API and even run the admin panel on a different server (connect to the database via remote MySQL) and dedicate a server API. How can I separate these parts without duplicating changes that I make in common parts like models? I thought of creating them as two branches in a Git repository. Is there a better way to do this separation or the whole optimization that is easier to maintain?

**Update:** The issue I'm facing is the response time. I put the following code into my routes, and it takes 400-600ms to respond.

```php
Route::any('/test2', function() 
{
    return "test";
});
```

I tested it on two different servers, and the configuration is good enough, I think (10GB ram - 4 CPU core 3.6Ghz). By the way, I have less than 1k requests per hour for now, and soon I'm looking at 5k-20k at most.

Comment: As you read in the answers, creating packages is the best option. I use this repo to build a boilerplate. https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager. If you use github, or similar, please read through this information first: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Answer (score 0):

I think dividing your source code into modules is good enough. Give a look to [Laravel Module](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to do as the creator of the Framework (Taylor): Packages and use `Composer`.
In the Laravel community, you have many Packages available like Horizon, Nova, Telescope, Spatie/* etc.
If you want to add them you just have to add a Composer dependency and it just work out of the box.
You can do the same with your code that will be in both project like Models etc.
Every Package has its own Git repo.
This is a more *Laravel* way to do it than separate into Module (compared to Symphony world). Laravel doesn't come with Modules at its core.

**Now about separating projects:**
As i read your need, i am not sure you will have performance issue if you run the API and the admin panel on the same project unless you have millions of http calls per hours.
I am currently working on a project with a lot of code for the client side, we also have an api with thousands of call per hours and everything is fine. We also run Nova for the internal backend.
You should consider that when you will have those scale problem, you will probably have database problem too and maybe servers problems (bandwith, memory, cost etc).
To be scalable 100% is not an easy task.
In my opinion, when you face it, solve it. Separating the Api/admin pannel at the beginning could be too much overhead to start/maintain a project.

Comment: so I should create a package that has the common parts like models, libraries, etc, and two separate laravel projects that have the common part as a dependency in compoer.json am I understood it correctly?

Comment: thanks for the info. I really appreciate it if you could look at the update in question. I'm trying to fix this issue for several days and I thought this is because of the many service providers that laravel load automatically but now I think that's might not be it